# Hola amigos, necesito ayuda urgente

Tags: android-studio

El problema es el siguiente, al recibir una palabra debo crear un codigo donde la palabra retorne pero en mayusculas y minusculas ejemplo-- paneton--PaNeToN. Aqui les dejo mi intent, solo capturo las letras de orden impar de la palabra y las convierto en mayuscula.

```
public void palabra(View v) {
    String p = "",im="",ip="",m="";
    int k=0;
    String a = et1.getText().toString();
    int z=p.length();
    for(int i=0;i< z;i++){
        p=a.substring(i,i+1);
        k=i%2;
        if(k==0){
            m=m+p;
        }
        im=m.toUpperCase();
    }
    tv1.setText(im);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero: trata de darle nombres significativos a las variables.

Segundo: la variable `z` siempre sera cero por que `p` la inicializas con una cadena vacia y cuando llegues al for `z` ya vale cero.

Tercero: la variable `m` siempre la terminas convirtiendo en mayuscula.

Cuarto: la variable `p` es la que debes de aplicarle el `toUpperCase` basandote en el resultado de `k`, digamos que te falta un else.

Te dejo una funcion para que la pruebes, la analices y la compares con lo que tienes mas las observaciones que te deje arriba.

```
public String IntervaloMayusculas(String str)
{
    String tempStr = str.toLowerCase();
    String newStr = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < tempStr.length(); i++) {
        if(i % 2 == 0)
            newStr += Character.toUpperCase(tempStr.charAt(i));
        else
            newStr += tempStr.charAt(i);
    }

    return newStr;
}
```